# How can I translate specific values in multiple columns in a spark dataframe, using a map?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm using Apache Spark 3.3 and scala.

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, where each column can (but does not have to) contain an untranslated id value.

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ValueX | @id/bar@ | ABC |
| @id/foo@ | ValueY | DEF |

I also have a map with all of these ids and their translations.

@id/foo@ => Foo;
@id/bar@ => Bar

Now i want to check every column and translate only the values which contain an id.

I already tried to convert the map to a dataframe and then join the two dataframes, but this only works for a single column at a time and I have to specify every column.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: What is your expected output? And does the original DF contains data extracted like "@id/foo@", or it will be id only like "2", "4",... then you want to translate id into a value as your map function? If so you could you provide your map function for testing

Comment: The expected output would be a dataframe like the table from aboce, but the value "@id/foo@" in Col1 is now "Foo" and the value "@id/bar" is now "Bar" all the other values would stay the same. The original Dataframe looks like the table above. So some values are "normal" like ValueXYZ but in the some column there could be a value which looks like "@id/something@" and this would need to be translated.

Comment: Please check my answer and see if it works as your intended

Answer (score 0):

You could use `udf` with `rlike` function to achieve this. I assumed that the map rule is predefined. But you could use regex to create a dynamic Map like `@idx/valuey@ -> Valuey` too.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()


// Define the translation map
val translationMap = Map("@id/foo@" -> "Foo", "@id/bar@" -> "Bar")

// Define the input dataframe
import spark.implicits._
val inputDF = Seq(("ValueX", "@id/bar@", "ABC"), ("@id/foo@", "ValueY", "DEF"))
  .toDF("Col1", "Col2", "Col3")
//+--------+--------+----+
//|    Col1|    Col2|Col3|
//+--------+--------+----+
//|  ValueX|@id/bar@| ABC|
//|@id/foo@|  ValueY| DEF|
//+--------+--------+----+

// Create an udf function, which take value from DF as Key, and convert it to Value
// based on aboved translationMap
val translateId = udf((id: String) => translationMap.getOrElse(id, id))

// Select all columns' value and apply function to each with syntax inputDF.columns.map(...): _*
// Check if column value have the format like "@id/.*@" (using regex)
// If true then apply udf function, if not then do nothing
val outputDF = inputDF.select(inputDF.columns.map(c => {
  when(col(c).rlike("@id/.*@"), translateId(col(c)))
    .otherwise(col(c)).alias(c) }): _*)

outputDF.show()

//+------+------+----+
//|  Col1|  Col2|Col3|
//+------+------+----+
//|ValueX|   Bar| ABC|
//|   Foo|ValueY| DEF|
//+------+------+----+
```